# NSURLProtocol and post upload progress

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlprotocol

I am using a subclass of NSURLProtocol to intercept all HTTP calls and modify the user agent as well as add a other http headers required by my server.

```
-(id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
      cachedResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse
              client:(id <NSURLProtocolClient>)client
{
    NSMutableURLRequest* lInnerRequest;
    //************************************************

    lInnerRequest = [request mutableCopy];
    [lInnerRequest setValue:@"MyUserAgent" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

    //************************************************
    self = [super initWithRequest:lInnerRequest
                   cachedResponse:cachedResponse
                           client:client];
    //************************************************
    if (self) 
    {
        self.innerRequest = lInnerRequest;  
    }
    //***********************************00*************
    [lInnerRequest release];
    //************************************************
    return self;
}
```

My protocol then uses an NSURLConnection

```
- (void)startLoading
{
self.URLConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:self.innerRequest delegate:self];
}
```

I then implement all the delegate method in the NSURLConnection by forwarding the call to the equivalent NSURLProtocolClient method.
This works well in general but when I am uploading data to the server, my code which is using NSURLConnection does not get called back on:

connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:

I understand why this is since I didn't implement that method in the NSURLProtocol as there are no equivalent NSURLProtocolClient method which can be used to report upload progress.

Has someone found any workaround for this?

Comment: this is a very interesting problem. did you ever find out a way to do this?

Comment: Having the same problem with the exact same use case. Does anyone know any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your code to make it a HTTP POST request:

```
[lInnerRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Comment: This does not work.
in any case  
`lInnerRequest = [request mutableCopy];` should have copied the method

Answer (score -1):

Use `setProperty:forKey:inRequest:` to save `NSURLConnection` and delegate object, then use `propertyForKey:inRequest:` to load `NSURLConnection` object and delegate object in custom `NSURLProtocol` class, when data sent, use the `NSURLConnection` object and delegate to call the delegate method